# Working with simple arrays in as3, but I'm getting weird behavior

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, hittest

My code goes like this:

```
if (hitTestObject(target.hit))
{    //pushes a number into an array
    stageRef.addChild(new Explosion(stageRef, x, y));
    myArray.push(myArray.length);
    removeSelf();


 //checks array length
if (myArray.length == 3){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    trace(myArray.length);
```

When I run this, I get a number and  a "Hit" Displayed in the output console, so every time the hittest is called, it should go up by 1 to show:

```
1
Hit
2
Hit
3
Hit
```

However, I'm getting seemingly random repeated numbers in this manner:

```
1
Hit
1
Hit
2
Hit
1 
Hit
3
Hit
3
Hit
5
Hit
1
Hit
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Your code has some errors that might be copy/paste, but also might be the source of your problem.  You have no close brackets on either of your conditional blocks.

Comment: It was from me copy and pasting, all the code has close brackets.

Comment: That being the case, you should probably edit your question with the correct code and with more than what you have here. Without knowing what code is in the removeSelf() function, it's not likely someone is going to be able to help. Is this code in a loop ? If so, if you had your brackets mixed up, it could cause many things you might not expect. (much like what we are seeing in your trace output)

Comment: Your trace is wrapped in a conditional that checks if length of myArray is equal to 3. So it should ALWAYS trace out 3. right ? The fact that we are not seeing that, leads me to believe the trace output you are posting is not from that code. Or is there some code on frame 2 that affects myArray ?